# Group data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL oracle, I have this requirement that I have to group the registered data by its supplier and by its request. Either I have to use supplier as my WHERE statement or I don't know. . . I'm having trouble with it, I currently have this sql statement:

```
SELECT
F1.order_no,
F1.code,
F1.disp_order,
F1.lvl,
F1.description,
F3.state,
F2.supplier_id
FROM tbl_main F1
LEFT JOIN tbl_pattern F2
ON F1.order_no = F2.order_no
AND F1.code = F2.code
LEFT JOIN tbl_child F3
ON F1.order_no = F3.order_no
AND F1.code = F3.code
```

This are the data registered to the table:

tbl_main

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |
| RM001-01 | 2    | 1          |  2  | HK140904-1B |
| RM001-01 | 3    | 2          |  3  | HK140904-1C |
| RM001-01 | 4    | 3          |  4  | HK140904-1D |
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |
| RM001-01 | 6    | 5          |  2  | HK140904-1F |
| RM001-01 | 7    | 6          |  3  | HK140904-1G |
| RM001-01 | 8    | 7          |  3  | HK140904-1H |
| RM001-01 | 9    | 8          |  4  | HK140904-1I |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

tbl_pattern

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | pattern | supplier_id | request_no |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |    1    |    0002     |20181001-001|
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |    1    |    0009     |20181001-002|
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |    1    |    0009     |20181001-003|
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

tbl_parent

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | request_no |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |20181001-001|
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |20181001-002|
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |20181001-003|
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
```

tbl_child

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | state  | request_no |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+------------+
| RM001-01 | 2    | 1          |  2  | HK140904-1B |    0   |20181001-001|
| RM001-01 | 6    | 5          |  2  | HK140904-1F |    3   |20181001-001|
| RM001-01 | 7    | 6          |  3  | HK140904-1G |    1   |20181001-002|
| RM001-01 | 8    | 7          |  3  | HK140904-1H |    3   |20181001-002|
| RM001-01 | 9    | 8          |  4  | HK140904-1I |    1   |20181001-002|
| RM001-01 | 3    | 2          |  3  | HK140904-1C |    0   |20181001-003|
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+------------+
```

Below are some sample results of the query needed, I think I need to do it by supplier_id or/and request_no, provided that user selects a pattern but I don't know how:

If user selects 1st record in tbl_pattern,result is:

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | state  | supplier_id |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |    2   |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 2    | 1          |  2  | HK140904-1B |    0   |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 3    | 2          |  3  | HK140904-1C |        |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 4    | 3          |  4  | HK140904-1D |        |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |        |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 6    | 5          |  2  | HK140904-1F |    3   |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 7    | 6          |  3  | HK140904-1G |        |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 8    | 7          |  3  | HK140904-1H |        |    0002     |
| RM001-01 | 9    | 8          |  4  | HK140904-1I |        |    0002     |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

If user selects 2nd record in tbl_pattern,result is:

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | state  | supplier_id |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 2    | 1          |  2  | HK140904-1B |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 3    | 2          |  3  | HK140904-1C |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 4    | 3          |  4  | HK140904-1D |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |    2   |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 6    | 5          |  2  | HK140904-1F |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 7    | 6          |  3  | HK140904-1G |    1   |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 8    | 7          |  3  | HK140904-1H |    3   |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 9    | 8          |  4  | HK140904-1I |    1   |    0009     |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

If user selects 3rd record in tbl_pattern,result is:

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | state  | supplier_id |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          |  1  | HK140904-1A |    2   |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 2    | 1          |  2  | HK140904-1B |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 3    | 2          |  3  | HK140904-1C |    3   |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 4    | 3          |  4  | HK140904-1D |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 5    | 4          |  5  | HK140904-1E |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 6    | 5          |  2  | HK140904-1F |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 7    | 6          |  3  | HK140904-1G |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 8    | 7          |  3  | HK140904-1H |        |    0009     |
| RM001-01 | 9    | 8          |  4  | HK140904-1I |        |    0009     |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

The state column is automatically set to '2' if it exists in tbl_parent

Comment: Sample results? Don't you want the same result each time (when having the same table data)?

Comment: Most people here want data as formatted text, not images. And left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: @jarlh I have updated it. It didn't allow me to post my question before because it says it just contain codes.

Comment: Great, looks much better now!

Comment: @jarlh I have included sample results before

Comment: Yes, but why 3 different results? From the same query???

Comment: @jarlh The query provided is what I have, it is still not fixed. I wanted to group the data, add a WHERE or so just to achieve the sample results

Comment: A query returns 1 result, not 3 different results... Which result do you want?

Comment: @jarlh Of course. I just want to provide a sample result if WHERE clause is changed. (provided that user selects a pattern - Added this to question)

Comment: What are the tables' primary keys? Looks like composite keys to me. This will make a big difference on how to write the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner except that supplier_id only exists in tbl_pattern

Comment: I agree with @thorsten: you seem unclear about the business rules you need to implement, and unfortunately that means we can't understand what you need to do either. We can't help you until you have explained what you want. Start by explaining the purpose of the tables and the relationships between them. Also the meaning of the columns. Please try to avoid using words which are SQL keywords when you mean something else. For instance you say *grouping by supplier* but your query doesn't aggregate: so you don't want GROUP BY. Maybe you meant *filter by supplier*?

Comment: How do you get the result state? I only see a `state` in `tbl_child`. That table doesn't have an entry for `code` 1, but in two of your results there is `state` 2 for `code` 1. How come?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The state column is automatically set to '2' if it exists in tbl_parent. I have included this at the bottom part. I'm sorry I can't seem to explain well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is really hard to understand. From how I see it:

1. Pick one record of `tbl_pattern`.
2. Take all records of `tbl_main`. That's a `CROSS JOIN`.
3. If a `tbl_main` record matches the `tbl_pattern` record and the `tbl_pattern` record matches a row in `tbl_parent` then `status` is 2.
4. If a `tbl_main` record plus the `tbl_pattern` record's `request_no` matches a row in `tbl_child` then this row's status is to be shown.

One possibility is to look up the status in the `SELECT` clause.

```
select 
  m.*, 
  p.supplier_id,
  case 
    when p.order_no = m.order_no 
    and p.code = m.code
    and p.disp_order = m.disp_order
    and p.lvl = m.lvl
    and p.description = m.description
    and (p.order_no, p.code, p.disp_order, p.lvl, p.description, p.request_no) in
    (
      select order_no, code, disp_order, lvl, description, request_no
      from tbl_parent
    ) then 2
    else
    (
      select state
      from tbl_child c
      where c.order_no = m.order_no
        and c.code = m.code
        and c.disp_order = m.disp_order
        and c.lvl = m.lvl
        and c.description = m.description
        and c.request_no = p.request_no
    )
  end as status
from tbl_pattern p
cross join tbl_main m
where p.order_no = 'RM001-01'
  and p.code = 1
  and p.disp_order = 0
  and ...;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me explain the requirements. I can't put the requirements into correct english words, I'm not good at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the below mentioned columns (F1.order_no,F1.code,F1.disp_order,F1.lvl,F1.description,F3.state,F1.supplier_id)

then you have to write everything in group clause. such as:-

```
SELECT
F1.order_no,
F1.code,
F1.disp_order,
F1.lvl,
F1.description,
F3.state,
F1.supplier_id
FROM tbl_main F1
LEFT JOIN tbl_pattern F2
ON F1.order_no = F2.order_no
AND F1.code = F2.code
LEFT JOIN tbl_child F3
ON F1.order_no = F3.order_no
AND F1.code = F3.code

group by F1.order_no, F1.code, F1.disp_order, F1.lvl, F1.description, F3.state, F2.supplier_id, F3.request_id ;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: because in the question user said he want to group the data of main_table by supplier_id and request_id.

Comment: It seems like the user doesn't know what he/she wants.

Comment: I just answered to the question. Just to add one thing, we can use group by even if no aggregate function is involved. eg. 
select department_id , job_id from employees
group by department_id, job_id;

Comment: Right, but isn't that the same thing as `select distinct department_id, job_id`?